# NSURLRequest setting body to null when NTLM

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using Charles to view traffic between my app and server. There are 3 steps in the NTLM handshake. 2 failures and then success. However, on the success step, my NSURLRequest body is now null. I'm not setting this anywhere in my app, and can only assume its somewhere deep inside the iOS framework itself.

Once I am authenticated, the requests body stay what they should. Its only during the handshake that it breaks.

FWIW, here's my piece of code that sets the auth block

```
[[operation HTTPRequestOperation] setWillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeBlock:^(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge) {
    if (challenge.previousFailureCount <= 0)
    {
        NSURLCredential *credential = [self credential];
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    } else
    {
        [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NSNotificationName_authenticationFailed object:nil];
        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}];
```

Has anyone else run across this?